# Dual boot Arch Linux with Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, arch-linux, bootloader

On my Acer laptop I have Windows 10 installed on `/dev/sda4` and the ESP partition is `/dev/sda2`.

As described in the [Beginner's Guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_guide) I installed Arch Linux on a newly created partition `/dev/sda5` and swap `/dev/sda6` with the Windows 10 created ESP  `/dev/sda2` as `/boot`.

As the bootloader I chose `systemd-boot` which is recommended by the guide if the motherboard is UEFI (which it is).

I configured the `/boot/loader/loader.conf` as follows:

```
timeout 10
default arch
```

I created an entry for `arch.conf` at `/boot/loader/entries/arch.conf` as follows;

```
title          Arch Linux
linux          /vmlinuz-linux
initrd         /initramfs-linux.img
options        root=/dev/sda5 rw
```

But after rebooting Windows 10 boots by default. I couldn't even see the bootloader menu. Also no option to select the Linux boot loader in the boot options. What am I doing wrong?

Note: Both `fastboot`(Windows 10) and `secureboot` (UEFI) are off.

In the question [Windows 10 / Linux Dual Boot - Boot-loader Problems](https://superuser.com/questions/952026/windows-10-linux-dual-boot-boot-loader-problems)  the OP uses GRUB for the bootloader. In my case I'm using `systemd-boot`. And in my setup `fastboot` aka `fast startup` is already disabled.

`#efibootmgr -v` returns all my boot options. It has the Linux boot manager in the list, but the boot order didn't specify anything about it. So, I manually edited the boot order by `# efibootmgr -o 1003,1001,2001`. But, the problem is the same. The boot order is reverted back after an reboot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10 / Linux Dual Boot - Boot-loader Problems](http://superuser.com/questions/952026/windows-10-linux-dual-boot-boot-loader-problems)

Comment: @Moab I saw this question earlier. It's different than mine. I've explained it through an edit to my post. Also I've already done the answer that is accepted but the problem persist.

Comment: You sure you've ran `bootctl install` appropriately? Sounds like systemd-boot is not properly registered / made default in the NVRAM. Check the output of `efibootmgr` in Arch live and take a look at your UEFI boot menu.

Comment: @TomYan I'm positive that I ran `bootctl install` correctly

Comment: No Moab, this is NOT a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/952026/windows-10-linux-dual-boot-boot-loader-problems

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I have tried following

```
#efibootmgr -v
```

This returns all my boot options. It has Linux boot manager (1003) in the list but boot order didn't specify any thing about it. So, I manually edited the boot order by

```
# efibootmgr -o 1003,1001,2001
```

But, the problem is same. Boot order is reverted back after an reboot.
So I checked if Linux boot manager is visible to `bcd` store in Windows 10

```
bcdedit /enum firmware
```

`bcd` store contains my Linux boot manager. So I ran

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\systemd\systemd-bootx64.efi
```

in an elevated command prompt. This command will make Windows boot loader to call the Linux boot manager without directly calling Windows 10.

This does solve my problem. Now I've a dual boot Windows 10 and Arch Linux on the same HDD.

Comment: Still unsolved using efibootmgr... seems strange that we have to go into Windows to change those variables... Nobody knows why...

Comment: from https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#Windows_changes_boot_order :
"Some motherboards override by default any settings set with efibootmgr by Windows if it detects it. This is confirmed in a Packard Bell laptop."